# How to structure my Higher Order Component with React/Redux/Formik and Yup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, formik, yup

I have 2 separate views. Both of them utilize the same form. The form lives in a Modal. The form works perfectly inside the first view **(The Create Mode)**.

Now I want to add another one, for the **(Edit Mode)**. The only difference is that the Edit Mode needs the values of the actual Item **(The user in our case)**.

I understand how Higher-Order Components work, in general. But my current configuration is using `Redux, Formik and Yup` for getting Data, Form handling and Validation respectively.

I tried a few examples online, but none of them fit my case scenario. And here lies the problem. How much functionality should I move to the Higher-Order Component?

Functionality One:
Where the actual form should live. The component, or the HOC? `Code Below:`

Should I move it, in the HOC? Since it is the exact same form. If yes why?

Functionality 2:
I am doing form validation with Yup. I have moved this functionality into the HOC, but now, I am not able to have ValidatioSchema passed to the Form Component. `Code Below`:

Functionality 3:
How to deal with the Modal. The Modal is a little bit tricky. I have decided to use it stand alone, in each separate screen. Is this correct or should I include it in the HOC?

**My HOC:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

import { createUser, updateUser } from './service';
import { listGroups } from '../groups/service';

const AddEditUserHOCForm = WrappedComponent => {
  class ViewUser extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      user: PropTypes.object,
      onCancel: PropTypes.func,
      onSave: PropTypes.func,
      status: PropTypes.string,
      values: PropTypes.object,
      errors: PropTypes.object,
      isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool,
      handleChange: PropTypes.func,
      handleSubmit: PropTypes.func,
      setStatus: PropTypes.func
    };

    static defaultProps = {
      user: {},
      onCancel: () => { },
      onSave: () => { },
      status: '',
      values: {},
      errors: {},
      isSubmitting: false,
      handleChange: () => { },
      handleSubmit: () => { },
      setStatus: () => { }
    };

    state = {
      groups: [],
      isRetrievingData: false
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
        isRetrievingData: true
      });
      return new Promise([listGroups()])
        .then(values => values.map(res => res.data))
        .then(([groups]) => {
          this.setState({
            isRetrievingData: false,
            groups
          });
        })
        .catch(({ message = 'Could not retrieve data from server.' }) => {
          this.setState({
            isRetrievingData: false
          });
          this.props.setStatus(message);
        });
    }

    handleCancel = () => {
      const { onCancel } = this.props;

      if (onCancel) {
        onCancel();
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...this.props}
          {...this.state}
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
          onCancel={this.handleCanel}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  const UserValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string('Provide a Username').required('Username is Required'),
    password: Yup.string().email('Provide a Valid email Address'),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string('Enter your password again')
      .required('Password Confirmation is Required')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match')
  });

  const NewUserFormHOC = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: ({ user }) => ({ ...user }),
    UserValidationSchema,

    handleSubmit: (values, { props, setSubmitting, setStatus }) => {
      const saveUser = values.username ? updateUser : createUser;
      return saveUser(values)
        .then(() => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          setStatus('');
          props.onSave(values);
          props.onCancel();
        })
        .catch(({ message, response: { data } }) => {
          setSubmitting(false);
          setStatus(data || message);
        });
    },

    displayName: 'ViewUser'
  })(ViewUser);
  return NewUserFormHOC;
};

export default AddEditUserHOCForm;
```

**And here is my Form Component:**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Formik, Form, Field } from 'formik';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AddEditUserHOCForm from './components/AddEditUserHOC'

import LensesSelect from './data/ReactSelectComponent';
import formPropTypes from '../constants/formPropTypes';

import { listGroups } from '../groups/service';

class UserCreateForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...formPropTypes,
    username: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string,
    password: PropTypes.string,
    confirmPassword: PropTypes.string,
    groupSelect: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    email: ''
  };

  state = {
    type: 'password',
    groups: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchListGroups();
  }

  fetchListGroups = () => {
    listGroups().then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ groups: data });
    });
  };

  mapListGroupToSelect = () => {
    const { groups } = this.state;
    return groups.map(group => ({
      label: group.name,
      value: group.name
    }));
  };

  togglePasswordMask = e => {
    const { type } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      passwordIsMasked: !prevState.passwordIsMasked,
      type: type === 'password' ? 'input' : 'password'
    }));
  };

  selectOnChangeCallback = response => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('selectOnChangeCallback', response);
  };

  render() {
    const { type } = this.state;
    const selectData = this.mapListGroupToSelect();
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: ''
          }}
          // validationSchema={createUserValidationSchema}
          onSubmit={values => {
            // same shape as initial values
            console.log(values);
          }}
        >
          {({ errors, touched }) => (
            <Form>
              <div className="my-3">
                <label>
                  Username <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <Field name="username" type="text" className="form-control rounded-0" />
                {errors.username && touched.username ? (
                  <div className="text-danger">{errors.username}</div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="my-3">
                <label>email</label>
                <Field name="email" type="email" className="form-control rounded-0" />
                {errors.email && touched.email ? (
                  <div className="text-danger">{errors.email}</div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="my-3">
                <label>
                  Password <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                  <Field type={type} name="password" className="form-control rounded-0 mr-2" />
                  <span
                    className={type === 'password' ? 'fa fa-eye fa-lg' : 'fa fa-eye-slash fa-lg'}
                    onClick={this.togglePasswordMask}
                  />
                </div>
                {errors.password && touched.password ? (
                  <div className="text-danger">{errors.password}</div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="my-3">
                <label>
                  Confirm Password <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <Field name="confirmPassword" type={type} className="form-control rounded-0" />
                {errors.confirmPassword && touched.confirmPassword ? (
                  <div className="text-danger">{errors.confirmPassword}</div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div className="my-3">
                <label>
                  Select Group <span className="text-danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <ReactSelectComponent
                  isMulti={false}
                  options={selectData}
                  onChangeCallback={this.selectOnChangeCallback}
                />
              </div>
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary rounded-0 float-right my-5">
                <span className="mx-2">Create User</span>
              </button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default AddEditUserHOCForm(UserCreateForm);
```

I understand this is a lot of code to pure through. But I am at a loss. Don't really know what I should include where.

To me, I need the form(Formik) and Yup, along with Redux on the HOC. And then Add the Data depending on the view. Please I really need some guidance and some examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

React is great, but it gives you too much freedom. In my opinion, you have to have SOLID principles applied to your components.

As you can read through the web, your component should only do one thing and do it well.

So. If i were to do it, i would have the form in one folder with one file representing its presentational configuration and another/s with business logic. You can do the second part as one HOC.

Let´s say, UserForm.js, withUserValidations, withUserActions. Then wrapp the whole thing.

Then you would just have to use it where you want. I hope it helps.